# Find start of rainfall season with specific conditions

Tags: python, datetime

I want to implement this rule to get the start of the rainfall season (according to Sivakumar): The start of the rainfall season corresponds to a **date X** on which an amount of 20mm of rain will have been collected in 3 consecutive days after May 1st without rain of more than 7 days.

So, there should be 3 conditions:

1. **X** is after the 1st May
2. the total rain in the next 3 days after **X** should be >= 20 mm
3. there should be rain between the 4th and the 10th day after **X**

Here is a year of rainfall data in form of dictionary. Convert it into dataframe to try out your code.

```
{'Date': {0: Timestamp('1931-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('1931-01-02 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('1931-01-03 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('1931-01-04 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('1931-01-05 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('1931-01-06 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('1931-01-07 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('1931-01-08 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('1931-01-09 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('1931-01-10 00:00:00'),
  10: Timestamp('1931-01-11 00:00:00'),
},
 'Rain': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,}}
```

Comment: Hi admin, please which details should I add to my question?

Comment: for year, df in inter_Bafoulabe.groupby(inter_Bafoulabe["Date"].dt.year):
    m1 = df['Date'].dt.month >= 5
    m2 = df['Rain'].shift(1).rolling(3).sum().shift(-4) >= 20
    m3 = df['Rain'].shift(3).rolling(7).sum().shift(-9) - df['Rain'].rolling(3).sum().shift(-2) > 0
    day = df.loc[m1 & m2 & m3, 'Date'].iloc[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if not df[m1 & m2 & m3].empty else 'Day not found'
    print(f"{year}: {day}")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Condition 1:

```
cond_1 = df["Date"].dt.month >= 5
```

Condition 2:

```
cond_2 = df["Rain"].shift(-3).rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum() >= 20
```

Condition 3:

```
cond_3 = df["Rain"].shift(-4).rolling(6, min_periods=1).max() > 0
```

And combine:

```
df[cond_1 & cond_2 & cond_3].iloc[0]["Date"]
```